# How do I handle datetime with no day in a linq comparison?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am given two dates as strings like this:

```
Beginning month:  10
Beginning year: 2010
Ending month:  01
Ending Year 2020
```

I want to query my entity and get everything that is equal or between these ranges.

So, I want everything from 10/2010 to 01/2020.

I have this code and I got stuck on how to convert the date correctly and the comparison:

```
     dollartotals = (from x in se.AchBatches
      where x.CompanyCode == company &&
            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeSubmitted) >=  
              // stuck here
      select x.DollarTotal).Sum();
```

How do I handle the individual month/year strings and make a date comparison without a day?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: This appears to be linq-to-entities query.  What version of Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core are you using?  Please update your tags appropriately.

Comment: `How do I handle the individual day/year strings and make a date comparison without a day?` so you just want to compare the years?

Comment: @devNull I actually want to compare the month and year.

Comment: And the DATE part? Correct? 

Why not just `>= myDatetime.Date` ??

Comment: @ErocM so you have the month and the year? Not the day and the year? If so, you should update the question since it currently says you have the day and the year

Comment: @AustinTFrench Not sure how I'd do that without the day.

Comment: @all sry fixed it to the correct word instead of day it should have been month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check against the actual datetime submitted, not a truncated version of it.

The key is to build actual datetimes in advance, then just do a regular date window check.

Assume you have four strings as listed in your question:

```
//you might use TryConvert or a Try block here to validate your string data...
int beginYear = Integer.Convert(strBeginYear);
int beginMonth = Integer.Convert(strBeginMonth);
int endYear = Integer.Convert(strEndYear);
int endMonth = Integer.Convert(strEndMonth);

DateTime start = new DateTime(beginYear, beginMonth, 1);
DateTime endLimit = new DateTime(endYear, endMonth, 1).AddMonths(1);

dollartotals = (from x in se.AchBatches
      where x.CompanyCode == company &&
            x.DateTimeSubmitted >= start &&
            x.DateTimeSubmitted < endLimit
      select x.DollarTotal).Sum();
```

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding but wouldn't that give me an extra day on the ending month, the 1st day of the additional month?

Comment: No because the comparison is less than.  This accounts up to the very last tick of time on the previous day, but does not go into the next month.

Comment: doh yup ty I missed that, trying it out now ty for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> I want everything from 10/2010 to 01/2020.

Not sure if you want a DateTime sequence with every Tick between those dates, or every second, or every Day. Let's assume you want every Day: All Days from startDate.Date until and inclusive endDate.Date.

I use StartDate.Date, so if StartDate is 2020-02-05 13:20:14, then you still get February 5th 2020 at 00:00:00

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DateTime lastDate = endDate.Date;
    DateTime date = startDate.Date;
    while (date <= lastDate)
    {
        yield return date;
        date = date.AddDays(+1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var allDaysOfFebruary2020 = GetDateRange(new DateTime(2020, 01, 01),
                                         new DateTime(2020, 02, 29));
```

You'll get the sequence from 1st February 2020 until and inclusive 29th February 2020.

Comment: The question is not seeking to create a sequence of `DateTime` values between a start and an end month/date, it's asking how to _filter_ for records that occur between a given start month and end month.

Comment: To keep only those objects of a sequence that are in another sequence, one uses Where( (x) => OtherSequence.Contains(x)). My reply focused on how to create a query for OtherSequence. I thought the Contains part was obvious

Comment: Well, obvious to you and me might not be obvious to everyone.  That will work, although given the 9-year date range in the question this would end up generating a sequence of 3400+ `DateTime` values that must be searched for every record.  Also, you don't show how the start and end `DateTime` values would be determined programmatically since you've hard-coded their component values.  To be honest, I feel like by focusing on just that one sentence you've missed the point of the question.